# RoR jQuery Check/Uncheck Specific Items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I'm currently building a RoR webpage. I'm trying to build a checkbox that helps select certain options in a form when checked. And when the check box is unchecked, it will automatically uncheck said selected options.

For example:

```
        <form id='list'><br>
            1<input type='checkbox' value='1' />
            2<input type='checkbox' value='2' />
            3<input type='checkbox' value='3' />
            4<input type='checkbox' value='4' />
            5<input type='checkbox' value='5' />
            CheckAnimal<input type='checkbox' name='checkanimal' onclick='checkAnimal()'><br>
        </form>
```

And JavaScript:

```
    <script language='JavaScript'>
        function checkAnimal () {
            var values = ['1', '2', '4', '5'];
            if (checked == false){checked = true}else{checked = false}
            $("#list").find('[value=' + values.join('], [value=') + ']').prop("checked", true);
        }   
    </script>
```

In JavaScript, without `if (checked == false){checked = true}else{checked = false}`, the options (1,2,4,5) will be selected when clicking on "CheckAnimal" checkbox. However, if I add the code back, the checkbox will not work at all.

By the way, these codes only work in JSFiddle and doesn't work in my local environment and I have no idea why.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yddq6/

The codes are all in document "_form.html.erb" and Google CDN (jQuery 1.10.2) `<head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>`) is in the .erb file as well.

Please kindly help!

Comment: Thank you so much for resolving my issue quickly, guys! I wish I could choose both of you as best answers. Both solutions work perfectly :) I "best answered" Joe since he posted his solution earlier. Thanks again for everything. Really appreciate it!

Comment: And do you guys know why the codes don't work in my local environment? I'm using chrome at http://0.0.0.0:3000/ to test the function, and it doesn't work there only in JSFiddle. The codes are inside "_form.html.erb". Appreciate your wizard work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting up two different cases, why don't you just set the 4 checkboxes to the same status of the checkbox you're trying to match?

```
function checkAnimal() {
var values = ['1', '2', '4', '5'];
$("#list").find('[value=' + values.join('], [value=') + ']').prop("checked",
$("#checkAnimalCheckbox").prop("checked")); // Instead of true, pass the value of the CheckAnimal Checkbox
}
```

and add an ID to your HTML to single out the special checkbox.

```
    <input type='checkbox'ID="checkAnimalCheckbox" name='checkanimal' onclick='checkAnimal()'>
```

Here's a modded JSFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/yddq6/1/

Answer (score 0):

That's because in your code, `checked` is not defined, it should be `element.checked` and you should also pass the element to your function:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='checkanimal' onclick='checkAnimal(this)'>

function checkAnimal(elem) {
      var values = ['1', '2', '4', '5'];
      if (elem.checked == false) {
          var checked = true
      } else {
          var checked = false
      }
      $("#list").find('[value=' + values.join('], [value=') + ']')
                .prop("checked", checked);
 }
```

But I would use `.on()` and `.filter()` methods:

```
$('input[name="checkanimal"]').on('change', function() {
    $("#list input").filter(function() {
        return $.inArray(this.value, values) > -1;
    }).prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yddq6/2/